# Background colour based on cursor position, specific colour spectrums

Tags: javascript, html, rgb

I'm using the JS cursor position x/y to create a colour changing background in the RGB spectrum:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
var $width = ($(document).width())/255;
var $height = ($(document).height())/255;
var $pageX = parseInt(e.pageX / $width,10);
var $pageY = parseInt(e.pageY / $height,10);
$("body").css("background-color", "rgb("+$pageX+","+$pageY+","+$pageX+")");
});
```

That works like a charm (thanks Stack Overflow!)
But I wonder if it would be possible to use a specific colour spectrum as opposed to the full RGB spectrum? i.e. just reds from dark red through to pale red?
I'm thinking this would probably be quite complex and my understanding of JS is limited at best. So before I start puzzling away, is this kind of limited spectrum/pallette possible?

Comment: I think its better to use HSL. Than you can do one way the hue and the others the saturation and lightness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the RGB for a specific color:

```
$("body").css("background-color", "rgb("+($pageX + $pageY)/2+",0,0)");
```

or you use HSL values:

```
$("body").css("background-color", "hsl(0, "+($pageX/$width)+"%, "+($pageY/$height)+"%)");
```

The first number is a color from red (0) to blue (255)

Basically you can get every color palette you want, you just have to find the correct equation to calculate your colorvalues. So it's more of a mathematically/color room theory question

Comment: I'm a little bit baffled by what that is doing, but I think i've got it! Thankyou very much! first time on this site and this is the most fantastic result!

Answer (score 0):

Leave your reds on the maximum RGB value (255). This will create shades from pale to dark red.

```
$("body").css("background-color", "rgb(255,"+$pageY+","+$pageY+")");
```

Heres a JsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/n47wr7et/1/

Comment: Both the green and blue values need to be the same value. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Also fantastically helpful!